# Move the file pointer back after fseek

Tags: c, stdio, fseek

I know this question sounds silly, but I cannot figure out when I am modifying my file pointer. I just started learning how files work in C. I was doing a simple exercise where I have to write function that shows size of file and takes file pointer as parameter. This is my function:

```
int file_size_from_file(FILE *f)
{
    int size;
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        return -2;
    }
    fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(f);
    return size;
}
```

But the system shows that I cannot modify the file pointer. I thought that all I had to do is write  `fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);`   after `size...`  to set cursor back to original place but it didn't work.

This is how system check function:

```
FILE *f = fopen("bright", "r");

int pos = 7220;

fseek(f, pos, SEEK_SET);

printf("#####START#####");
int res = file_size_from_file(f);
printf("#####END#####\n");

test_error(res == 7220, "Funkcja file_size_from_file zwróciła nieprawidłową wartość, powinna zwrócić %d, a zwróciła %d", 7220, res);
test_error(ftell(f) == pos, "Function should not modify file pointer");

fclose(f);
```

After checking it says "FAIL - function should not modify file pointer "

Comment: "But system shows that I cannot modify file pointer": How does it?

Comment: How are you calling `file_size_from_file` function?

Comment: "...but it didn't work" - please edit your question and explain what "didn't work" means. Compile errors/run-time errors/unexpected results/demons from hell popped out of the electric socket and carried your computer off to eternal torment/all of the above/none of the above/other?

Comment: @daka  I edit all things you asked

Comment: @ybungalobill It uses code that I edited, it checks my function with that code and after that it says "FAIL - function should not modify file pointer"

Comment: While it's true that `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET)` should set the file pointer back to the beginning of the file, it doesn't appear that your code ever does this. ???

Comment: You moved the cursor in the file. You need to move it back. To is is back at the position it were.

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried adding fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET); at the end of function, that should move it back (at least I think so) but I still get the same FAIL when I pass code to system.

Comment: `0, SEEK_SET)` moves the cursor to the beginning of the file. You want to move to cursor to the 7220th position, from what I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should set the file back to the position it was in when called:

```
long int file_size_from_file(FILE *f)
  {
  long int size;
  long int pos;

  if(f==NULL)
    return -2;

  pos = ftell(f);

  fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
  size = ftell(f);
  fseek (f, pos, SEEK_SET);

  return size;
  }
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks it's worked, I fought that "fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);" will set cursor to start position. I have to figure out what fseek exactly do.

Comment: `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET)` will set `f` to point to the beginning of the file, not to the position it was set to previously. `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET)` is equivalent to `rewind(f)`